# Is the integral closure of a valuation ring in a finite separable extension of its fraction field étale?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, valuation-rings

Let $K$ be a field endowed with a rank (height) one valuation with completion $\hat{K}$, which is not discrete. Let $R$ be the valuation ring of $K$.

Let $L \subset \hat{K}$ be a separable finite field extension of $K$. Let $V$ be the valuation ring of $L$.

Is the inclusion $R \rightarrow V$ étale? Or even weakly étale?

What I know: $R$ is a valuation ring (hence a Prüfer domain), and $V$ is a torsion-free module over $R,$ so it is flat. These rings have same residue fields, and the maximal ideal of $R$ generates the maximal ideal of $V.$ In order to be able to conclude, the only thing that is missing is the condition of finitely presented, which I can't show to be true in general.

Comment: In order for $R \to V$ to be smooth, you also need the extension of residue fields to be separable.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly. In fact, I consider $L$ to be embedded in a completion of $K.$ Are you saying it is true with this added hypothesis?

Comment: Dear userm, you're right that for $R \to V$ to be étale, it should be finitely presented. Since $V$ is integral over $R$, this implies that $V$ should be a finitely generated $R$-module. I don't think this always holds (although I can't think of a counterexample in your situation) -- this condition is related to the notion of Japanese rings (see also Nagata ring). Also $V$ should be flat over $R$. If these two technical conditions are satisfied, then $R \to V$ is étale because the geometric fibers are non-singular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the map is flat: R is a Prüfer domain, so a torsion-free module should be flat. As you say it, all of the conditions for it to be étale are satisfied, except for possibly finitely presented. I edited accordingly.

Comment: you're right $V$ is automatically flat over $R$. Still there is something I don't get when you say $V$ is the integral closure of $R$: in general, the integral closure will rather be semi-local. Also, maybe it would be good if you put all your assumptions in your question, since otherwise it is difficult to give a definite answer.

Comment: Dear François, I think I made the mistake of thinking that the valuation ring of $L$ would be the integral closure of $R$ in $L.$ I am not sure anymore that this is true. Sorry for the confusion. What I want is to take $V$ to be the valuation ring of $L.$ Will add a few details.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT** I may have overlooked the assumption that $L$ is contained in $\hat{K}$. In general, if $v$ is a valuation of $K$ and $L/K$ is finite separable then $L \otimes_K \hat{K}$ is reduced and thus isomorphic to $\prod_i \hat{L}_i$ where the $\hat{L}_i$ are the completions of $L$ for the various valuations $v_i$ extending $v$. In your situation one of the $\hat{L}_i$ is equal to $\hat{K}$. Since the dimension of $L \otimes_K \hat{K}$ over $\hat{K}$ is equal to $[L:K]$, this means that there must exist some other completions, hence the extension of $v$ is not unique in your setting and the following examples don't apply directly. I'm leaving them however because they might be useful to answer the question. **END OF EDIT**

The following example, due to Ostrowski and mentioned in *The theory of classical valuations* by Ribenboim (Sect. 6.3), gives a situation where $V$ is not finitely presented over $R$, and thus not étale over $R$.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_2(2^{1/2^\infty})$ be the extension of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ obtained by adjoining the iterate square roots of $2$, endowed with the $2$-adic valuation $v$, with value group $\mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$, so $v$ has rank 1 and is not discrete. Consider the finite separable extension $L=K(\sqrt{-1})$. Then $v$ has a unique extension $v'$ to $L$ with ramification index and residual degree both equal to 1. Let $R$ be the valuation ring of $v$. Since $v$ has a unique extension to $L$, the integral closure $V$ of $R$ in $L$ is the valuation ring of $v'$. We are in a situation where $\sum_i e_i f_i < [L:K]$ using standard notations from ramification theory, and this implies that $V$ is not a finite $R$-module (see Endler, *Valuation theory*, Theorem 18.6).

Just after Ostrowski's example, Ribenboim gives another interesting example of a complete valued field $(K,v)$ of characteristic $p$ with $v$ non-discrete, and a separable extension $L/K$ of degree $p$, such that $v$ has a unique extension $v'$ in $L$, and the ramification index and the residual degree of $v'/v$ are both equal to 1. This gives another example where $V$ is not étale over $R$.

Since in your situation finite presentation is the only obstruction, one may wonder whether pro-étale extensions are more appropriate, in particular whether $V$ is always pro-étale over $R$.

Comment: Dear François, thanks for these examples anyway! And yes, it would already be helpful to know whether this map is weakly étale.